# MapBox markers stopped showing in the map after using dynamic data because the data comes late

Tags: android, retrofit, mapbox

i have implemented a mapbox and it works so fine with static markers data , but when i used dynamic data that comes from retrofit 2 , the markers are not showing anymore , here an example of the result of query test on postman:

```
[
    {
        "cyclist_id": 1,
        "title": "Bike Cyclist 1",
        "latitude": 35.785118,
        "longitude": 10.000871
    },
    {
        "cyclist_id": 2,
        "title": "Bike Cyclist 2",
        "latitude": 36.9001,
        "longitude": 10.90175
    },
    {
        "cyclist_id": 3,
        "title": "Bike Cyclist 3",
        "latitude": 35.900893,
        "longitude": 9.154924
    }
]
```

I am not sure if the map capture the data late or if the data itself is different of the static one and made it hard to the map for display,

Log.e() method show that the data come properly but i do not know if it is later or not

here the full code of the activity:

```
package com.example.miniprojetandroid.ui.activities;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.miniprojetandroid.R;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.MapService;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.RetrofitClient;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.BikeCyclist;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Circuit;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Community;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Shop;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Feature;
import com.mapbox.geojson.FeatureCollection;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Icon;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.IconFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.SymbolLayer;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconAllowOverlap;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconIgnorePlacement;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconImage;


public class MapBoxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapService apiService;
    private  ArrayList<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<Shop>();
    private  ArrayList<BikeCyclist> cyclists = new ArrayList<BikeCyclist>();
    private  ArrayList<Community> communities = new ArrayList<Community>();
    private  ArrayList<Circuit> circuits = new ArrayList<Circuit>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        apiService = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(MapService.class);

// Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
// object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.accessToken));

// This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the access token is configured.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_box);

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                fillDataShops();
                fillDataCircuits();
                fillDataCommunities();
                fillDataCyclists();


                //static markers and positions
                /*Shop shop1 = new Shop("bike shop 1",36.553015,10.592774);
                Shop shop2 = new Shop("bike shop 2",35.499414,10.824846);
                Shop shop3 = new Shop("bike shop 3",35.945377,9.451555);
                shops.add(shop1);
                shops.add(shop2);
                shops.add(shop3);
                Community com1 = new Community("Community 1", 37.276943 , 9.748186);
                Community com2 = new Community("Community 2", 35.427828, 10.934709);
                Community com3 = new Community("Community 3", 36.140808, 8.847307);
                communities.add(com1);
                communities.add(com2);
                communities.add(com3);
                BikeCyclist cyclist1 = new BikeCyclist("Bike Cyclist 1", 35.785118 , 10.000871);
                BikeCyclist cyclist2 = new BikeCyclist("Bike Cyclist 2", 36.900100  , 10.901750);
                BikeCyclist cyclist3 = new BikeCyclist("Bike Cyclist 3",35.900893 , 9.154924);
                cyclists.add(cyclist1);
                cyclists.add(cyclist2);
                cyclists.add(cyclist3);

                Circuit c1 = new Circuit("Circuit 1", 33.773035, 10.857805);
                Circuit c2 = new Circuit("Circuit 2", 36.882526, 8.957170);
                Circuit c3 = new Circuit("Circuit 3", 36.574341, 8.429827);
                circuits.add(c1);
                circuits.add(c2);
                circuits.add(c3);*/


                List<MarkerOptions> shopsOptions = new ArrayList<>();
                List<MarkerOptions> communitiesOptions = new ArrayList<>();
                List<MarkerOptions> cyclistsOptions = new ArrayList<>();
                List<MarkerOptions> circuitsOptions = new ArrayList<>();

                Log.e("Community LIST", communities.toString());
                for(Shop s : shops){
                    shopsOptions.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(s.getLatitude(),s.getLongitude())).setTitle(s.getTitle()) );
                }

                for(Community s : communities){
                    communitiesOptions.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(s.getLatitude(),s.getLongitude())).setTitle(s.getTitle()) );
                }

                for(BikeCyclist s : cyclists){
                    cyclistsOptions.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(s.getLatitude(),s.getLongitude())).setTitle(s.getTitle()) );
                }

                for(Circuit s : circuits){
                    circuitsOptions.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(s.getLatitude(),s.getLongitude())).setTitle(s.getTitle()) );
                }

                mapboxMap.addMarkers(shopsOptions);
                mapboxMap.addMarkers(cyclistsOptions);
                mapboxMap.addMarkers(communitiesOptions);
                mapboxMap.addMarkers(circuitsOptions);



                mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                        // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add data or make other map adjustments
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }



    public void fillDataShops(){

        Call<List<Shop>> call = apiService.getShops();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Shop>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Shop>> call, Response<List<Shop>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    shops.addAll(response.body());
                    Log.e("SHOP LIST", shops.toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Shop>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    public void fillDataCircuits(){

        Call<List<Circuit>> call = apiService.getCircuits();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Circuit>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Circuit>> call, Response<List<Circuit>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    circuits.addAll(response.body());
                    Log.e("Circuit LIST", circuits.toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Circuit>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    public void fillDataCommunities(){

        Call<List<Community>> call = apiService.getCommunities();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Community>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Community>> call, Response<List<Community>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    communities.addAll(response.body());
                    Log.e("Community LIST", communities.toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Community>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    public void fillDataCyclists(){

        Call<List<BikeCyclist>> call = apiService.getCyclists();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<BikeCyclist>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<BikeCyclist>> call, Response<List<BikeCyclist>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    cyclists.addAll(response.body());
                    Log.e("Cyclist LIST", cyclists.toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<BikeCyclist>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }


}
```

What i am trying to do is to display my markers data that comes from database in my map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct :D The problem lies with the timing.

Once the map has loaded you request the data for your markers. But you do not wait for this data to arrive, and you create the markers in the `onLoad()` callback of the map, instead of waiting for the data to arrive and then creating the markers in the `onResponse()` callback of the requests.

To get the markers to show, create them in the respective `onResponse()` callbacks of your http requests:

```
fillDataShops();
fillDataCircuits();
fillDataCommunities();
fillDataCyclists();
```

Example:

```
public void fillDataCircuits(){

        Call<List<Circuit>> call = apiService.getCircuits();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Circuit>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Circuit>> call, Response<List<Circuit>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    circuits.addAll(response.body());
                    // Create Markers here
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Circuit>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer  ,  can i ask you about how to add my current location on this map and draw route for the selected marker?